# npm cli with co/yield not ending

Tags: node.js, bash, node-commander

I'm attempting to write a `node cli` application.  It *works*, however, it doesn't return back to the command line (at least not in Windows, haven't tried yet in bash).  I have to `Ctrl+Break` out of the application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony

var chalk = require('chalk');
var co = require('co');
var prompt = require('co-prompt');
var program = require('commander');

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .option('-w, --workshop <workshop number>', 'workshop number to build')
    .parse(process.argv);

co(function* () {
    if (!program.workshop) {
        program.workshop = yield prompt('Workshop: ');
    }

    return yield Promise.resolve(true);
}).then(function() {
    console.log(chalk.bold.cyan('You entered: ') + program.workshop);
});
```

I've also tried it without the line `return yield Promise.resolve(true);` but that has no affect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found another solution in [this](https://github.com/tj/co-prompt/issues/9) co-prompt Github issue.

```
var co = require('co');
var prompt = require('co-prompt');

co(function* () {
    var value = yield prompt('Value: ')
    return value
}).then(function (value) {
    // do whatever you need with the value
    console.log(value)
}).then(function () {
    // when you are done you must pause stdin
    process.stdin.pause()
})

// now the process will exit normally
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested... I'm not sure if this is the *right* way, but:

1. I ended up removing

   `return yield Promise.resolve(true);`
2. Then adding as the last line of my `.then` function

   `process.exit(0);`

Again, not sure if this is the best approach, but it does work.